# Improve regular expression to end on quotation

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
>>> re.findall('http://www.rottentomatoes.com/.+', html)
['http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1129132-torque" class="see-all">Read More About This Movie On Rotten Tomatoes</a>']
```

How would I get this to match up until the `"`. I am trying to get the return to be:

```
http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1129132-torque
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy quantifier `?` to stop at the first `"`:

```
>>> html = 'http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1129132-torque" class="see-all">Read More About This Movie On Rotten Tomatoes</a>'
>>> re.search('(http://www\.rottentomatoes\.com/.+?)"', html).group(1)
'http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1129132-torque'
```

Comment: You should probably escape the first `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the **character(")** where you want to stop. Also add `?`, so that it stops at the first match.

```
>>> html='http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1129132-torque" class="see-all">Read More About This Movie On Rotten Tomatoes</a>'
>>> re.findall('http://www.rottentomatoes.com/.+?\"', html)
['http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1129132-torque"']
```